# How do I read in a csv with two double quotes as text qualifiers using R?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

How do I read in a csv with 2 double quotes as qualifiers and a comma inside the qualifiers i.e.

```
""V"",""W"",""X"",""Y"",""Z""
""            "",""A                    "",""*B           "",""C                  "",""D-E""
""            "",""a                     "",""*b            "",""c,c,c"",""d e         ""
""            "",""E                    "",""*F           "",""G                   "",""H-H""
```

using `fread` in `data.table` ?

Comment: You probably want to prepare your file before importing instead, something like `sed 's/""/"/g' input_file > output_file` (or sed -i with only input_file to replace in place)

Comment: Tensibai's solution will be more efficient but if you are not on a unix system and don't have sed, you can just import the file with the double quotes (using `fread`) and then do the replacement in R `fread(<your-file>, quote = '')[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub('^\"\"|\"\"$', '', x))]`, but may take a while depending on your machine (you just need to do it once and then save the new dataframe into a file without the double quotes)

Comment: The problem that I perhaps should have mentioned is that sometimes there are commas inside the text qualifiers. So `fread` actually can't read the data in. I will make the necessary edits.

Comment: Can you post an example file with 10 rows that are representative of the kind of problems you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` and `fread` as requested, you can do this.

The trick is to

1. fread each line in the file as a single column by setting `sep='~'` (or some other char that doesn't exist in the file) and setting `quote=''` (no quotes).
2. Then, remove the double quote at the start & end of the lines
3. `tstrsplit()` that single column into multiple columns using `"",""` as the pattern

`data.table::tstrsplit()` is a handy wrapper for `strsplit()` that returns the rows transposed as columns.

R code:

```
library(data.table)
# Read the file as a single column per line by picking 
#  a sep character that doesn't exist in the file. 
#  E.g. '~' doesn't exist in the OP's current sample data

DT <- fread( "OPs_new_input_example_file.csv", 
             sep='~', quote='', header=FALSE)

DT[, V1 := gsub('""(.*)""$', "\\1",V1)] # remove "" at start and end
DT <- DT[, tstrsplit(V1, '"",""') ] # strsplit and transpose rows to columns
DT
```

Result:

```
             V1                     V2             V3                   V4           V5
1:            V                      W              X                    Y            Z
2:               A                      *B             C                            D-E
3:              a                      *b                            c,c,c d e         
4:               E                      *F            G
```

Please feel free to post suggestions for improvements or alternative solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was innovative, however, there are still some problems. I have added an example that breaks in my edits. The error says it expected 5 fields but found 7. This is very strange to me.

Comment: I see what you mean. Problem is fread is picking up the commas as delimeters before anything else.   I'll try to amend the solution to account for that by using `quote='"'` in fread, then modifying the gsub call to look for the remaining single quotes.

Comment: Couldn't work around fread picking up the commas at the first stage so posted an alternative solution as above.

Comment: Aaah this is an exceptional solution! Welldone! Should you not be assigning along the way though?

Comment: Using `:=` in j as above is  'assign in place'. As column V1 already exists it replaces the original value.

Comment: Oh, you mean in the last step.  Yes, you're right!  now fixed.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you!